# PHP web page redirection. Localhost

Tags: php, mysql

I was making a IMS that the admin must login then redirect the web page to the main page, but it does not it continue to loop, infinite looping, the error says localhost has too many redirects..

This is my index code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!empty($_SESSION['KEY']))
{
header("location: datagrid_customer_info.php");

}
if(isset($_SESSION['blocked']))
{
header("location: blocked.php");
}
?>
```

This is my login page code: "I did not include the html code"

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['KEY']))
{
header("location:datagrid_customer_info.php");
}
?>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['btnLogin'])){
    require("_config.php");

    $txtEmail = $_POST['txtEmail'];
    $txtPassword = $_POST['txtPassword'];

    $STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM adm_login_info WHERE   
    cEmail=:txtEmail AND cPassword=:txtPassword");   
    $STH->bindparam(":txtEmail",$txtEmail);
    $STH->bindparam(":txtPassword",$txtPassword);
    $STH->execute();
    $ROW = $STH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $CTR = $STH->rowCount();
        if($CTR==1){
            $_SESSION['idLogin'] = $ROW['idLogin'];
            $_SESSION['KEY'] = 1;

            $STH = $DBH->prepare("UPDATE adm_login_info SET cLock=0, 
            cLastLogin = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') WHERE 
            idLogin=:idLogin");
            $STH->bindparam(":idLogin",$ROW['idLogin']);
            $STH->execute();

            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
            echo "alert('Welcome to Inventory Management System');";
            echo "window.location.href='datagrid_customer_info.php';";
            echo "</script>";
        }else{
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
            echo "alert('Login Error!');";
            echo "window.location.href='login.php';";
            echo "alert('INVALID USERNAME OR PASSWORD!!!!!');";
            echo "</script>";
        }   
}
?>
```

This is the main page code: "I also did not include the html, only the php code"

```
<?php
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['KEY']))
{
header('location: login.php');
}
?>
<?php
require_once("_config.php");
if(isset($_REQUEST['del_id']))
{

 $STH=$DBH->prepare("DELETE FROM inv_customer_info WHERE idCustomer=:id");
 $STH->bindparam(":id",$_REQUEST['del_id']);
 $STH->execute();
 header("Location: datagrid_customer_info.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: It looks like there's a loop due to `SESSION` cookies. Can you please post `datagrid_customer_info.php` code and tell us what steps you follow to produce the error?

Comment: The datagrid_customer_info.php is the main page code.. see above.. @Reversal

Comment: What version of php? Maybe try !isset() instead of empty() when checking the $_SESSION['KEY']

Comment: Dont you have to exit after setting the response header? Maybe there's some processing afterwards which is blocking the desired behaviour.

Comment: What do you mean exit? @JeanCarloMachado

Comment: Headers must appear before any content and if you are just redirecting is safer to exit after the header. ```header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
exit;```

Comment: As I thought, there is a loop redirect between `datagrid_customer_info.php` and `login.php`. 

If you reach one of those pages without any `$_SESSION['KEY']` set you'll bounce forever between the two. Maybe the error is due to the `if` in `login.php`: when you check if `$_SESSION['KEY']` is set you maybe want to remove the not `!`.